# Exporting JSON from fetch in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am working on exporting the JSON I get from a fetch. I know I have a binding issue, but I'm not completely sure on how I should proceed to bind my function to the current component. I have a quick example at this URL https://snack.expo.io/@mcmillster/c21pbG.

app.js

```
  import React from 'react';
    import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';
    import { getMovies } from './utility.js';

    export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state ={ 
      isLoading: true,
    }
    this.getMovies = getMovies.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
    this.getMovies;
    }



    render(){

      if(this.state.isLoading){
        return(
          <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 100}}>
            <ActivityIndicator/>
          </View>
        )
      }

      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
          <FlatList
            data={ this.state.data }
            renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear} 
 </Text>}
            keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

utility.js

```
export function getMovies() {
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          data: responseJson.movies,
        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook, you're not calling the `getMovies` function, you're just referencing it. Change `this.getMovies` to `this.getMovies()`

#### Solution

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.getMovies();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Didn't realize I was there and simply forgot to actually call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not try to set the state from your fetch function. Just call it, return data and handle them in your component.

app.js

```
[...]
private getMovies = async() => {
  const movies = await getMovies();
  if(movies){
    this.setState({...})
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.getMovies();
}
```

utility.js

```
export function getMovies() {
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson.movies;
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
        return;
      });
    }
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing it this way, or is this a more proper way of importing the fetch?

Comment: This way your function is ignorant, does not know what happens in the component that call it. Also you can reuse it simpler and, in my opinion, it's more coherent and consistent.